# Standard PayPal Sandbox Error Issue in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, payment-gateway, sandbox

I have configured WooCommerce in WordPress and enabled PayPal Standard Sandbox with a client PayPal account email Id.

When I purchase 3 downloadable products for a Total amount  of USD 3.25 with PayPal Standard payment gateway, I got this error:

> "Things don't appear to be working at the moment. Please try again later."…

I checked PayPal settings, it is attached with bank and credit card.

**Remember:** As can check its not business account nor I filled **"API credentials"**.

WooCommerce Paypal Settings screenshot:

[image: WooCommerce Paypal Settings]

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable **Paypal Sandbox option**, you need to get a [**testing developer account**](https://developer.paypal.com/) *(as specified in related settings… see below)*:

[image]

This testing account doesn't need to be attached with bank and credit card.

> That's why it doesn't work…

The **developer account** provide (for testing):

- Admins account (where you will get transactions, notifications, errors)
- Fake customers account for fake purchases.

Once registered your developer account, you will need to create a pair of admin + customers account for one URL shop.

Comment: Thanks @Loi for your answer, I had already set that settings. Problem was at client end, That PayPal account was not properly activated. Some formalities was pending from client(account holder). Now client has complete all formalities to activate account and its' working fine.